# Sacar fuera del div un elemento con droppable - JQUERY UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estoy haciendo con jquery ui, un elemento que debería poder arrastrarse y luego hacer drop en otro lugar(droppable). Ese elemento, se arrastra perfectamente pero el problema está en que está dentro de un div y cuando lo muevo no sale de ahí. El lugar donde debo soltarlo está fuera del div, por lo tanto, como puedo hacer para sacar mi elemento y poder dropearlo donde toca, porque por ahora cuando lo arrastro no sale fuera. Estoy usando Chromium y jquery touch pounch, además de bootstrap. Gracias.

Aquí el javascript:

```
<script> 
$( function() {
        $( ".list-group-item" ).draggable({
          revert: true
        });
        $( ".listaFav" ).droppable();
      } );
</script>
```

Aquí el html:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="article">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <picture>
                <img class="imagenLista" src="miimagen">
            </picture>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<div class="listaFav ui-widget-header"></div>
```

Comment: Existe un excelente ejemplo en la documentación de [`Droppable - Photo Manager`](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Pero mi problema está en que no puedo sacar el div que arrastro. En la documentación que me indicas, el div draggable ya está fuera. En mi ejemplo, el div draggable está dentro de otro div.

Comment: Si te fijas, en el ejemplo se puede sacar de un `droppble` (`gallery`) y llevar dentro de otro (`trash`) y viceversa.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias ;)